# Can´t use Stable Baselines 3 in Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, stable-baselines

I try to use [Stable Baselines 3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3) in my project. Still I can't use it, even after installing it in my Anaconda environment.

#### Python Script

```py
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
from env.project_env import *

env = ProjectEnv()
# It will check your custom environment and output additional warnings if needed
check_env(env)
```

#### Environment

```bash
# packages in environment at /Users/nito/opt/anaconda3/envs/project-rl-BA:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.15.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
astor                     0.8.1            py37hecd8cb5_0    anaconda
blas                      1.0                         mkl    anaconda
bottleneck                1.3.5            py37h4de8ad1_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                hb7f2c08_8    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                hb7f2c08_8    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h0d85af4_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.18.1               hca72f7f_0    anaconda
ca-certificates           2023.01.10           hecd8cb5_0  
cached-property           1.5.2                      py_0    anaconda
certifi                   2022.12.7        py37hecd8cb5_0  
cffi                      1.14.6           py37hda351d9_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    4.2.2                h97e5cf8_0  
fonttools                 4.38.0           py37h8052db5_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h4cff582_1    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py37hf985489_5    conda-forge
gast                      0.2.2                    py37_0    anaconda
gettext                   0.21.1               h8a4c099_0    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                hbcb3906_2    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h2e338ed_0    conda-forge
gnutls                    3.6.13               h756fd2b_1    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
grpcio                    1.42.0           py37ha29bfda_0    anaconda
gym                       0.19.0           py37h4c52d7d_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.6.0            py37h4a1dd59_0    anaconda
hdf5                      1.10.6               hdbbcd12_0    anaconda
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          hecd8cb5_3538    anaconda
jbig                      2.1               h0d85af4_2003    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   hac89ed1_2    conda-forge
keras                     2.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1    anaconda
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
kiwisolver                1.3.2            py37h737db71_1    conda-forge
lame                      3.100             hb7f2c08_1003    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 h577c468_0    conda-forge
lerc                      3.0                  he49afe7_0    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                hb7f2c08_8    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                hb7f2c08_8    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                hb7f2c08_8    conda-forge
libcxx                    12.0.0               h2f01273_0    anaconda
libdeflate                1.10                 h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2    anaconda
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2    anaconda
libiconv                  1.17                 hac89ed1_0    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                hc929b4f_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libprotobuf               3.20.1               h8346a28_0    anaconda
libtiff                   4.3.0                h17f2ce3_3    conda-forge
libvpx                    1.7.0                h378b8a2_0  
libwebp                   1.2.2                h28dabe5_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.2                h0d85af4_1    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h0d85af4_1004    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               hfe4f2af_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                he49afe7_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.1            py37h3147e9e_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           hecd8cb5_637    anaconda
mkl-service               2.4.0            py37h9ed2024_0    anaconda
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py37h4ab4a9b_0    anaconda
mkl_random                1.2.2            py37hb2f4e1b_0    anaconda
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  hca72f7f_2    anaconda
nettle                    3.6                  hedd7734_0    conda-forge
ninja                     1.10.2               h940c156_1    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.8.0            py37h5b83a90_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.5           py37h2e5f0a9_3    anaconda
numpy-base                1.21.5           py37h3b1a694_3    anaconda
openh264                  2.1.1                h8346a28_0  
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h6e7aa92_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1s               hca72f7f_0  
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
packaging                 23.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.3.5            py37h743cdd8_0  
pillow                    9.1.1            py37h1eb1bbc_1    conda-forge
pip                       22.3.1           py37hecd8cb5_0  
protobuf                  3.20.1           py37he9d5cce_0    anaconda
pthread-stubs             0.4               hc929b4f_1001    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyglet                    1.5.27           py37hf985489_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.13               hdfd78df_0    anaconda
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.10.2          cpu_py37h903acac_0  
pytz                      2022.7.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                hca72f7f_1    anaconda
scipy                     1.7.3            py37h8c7af03_0    anaconda
setuptools                61.2.0           py37hecd8cb5_0    anaconda
simpy                     4.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
sqlite                    3.38.5               h707629a_0    anaconda
stable-baselines3         1.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-base           2.0.0           mkl_py37h66b1bf0_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0            py37hecd8cb5_1    anaconda
tk                        8.6.12               h5d9f67b_0    anaconda
typing-extensions         4.4.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.4.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              14.0.0           py37h69ee0a8_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
wrapt                     1.13.3           py37hca72f7f_2    anaconda
x264                      1!157.20191217       h1de35cc_0  
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h35c211d_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h35c211d_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                hca72f7f_1    anaconda
zlib                      1.2.12               h4dc903c_2    anaconda
zstd                      1.5.2                h582d3a0_0    conda-forge
```

I tried to set up a new environment and installed stable baselines 3 with the pip installation in Anaconda, still nothing worked for me.

Comment: What do you mean nothing worked? Was there an error message? What's the output? Can you give details on that?